# dbt - jinja - bigquery - Query optimization

Tags: google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I have a model in `dbt` that calculates some stats per column (for example, `count_nulls`) and unions it with all other columns. This becomes an issue if the number of columns is huge. One of the datasets has around 700 columns and BigQuery complains `Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex`

```
#for each column in the table
{% for col in results_list %}
(
SELECT
      COUNTIF({{ col }} is NULL) as count_nulls,
      COUNTIF({{ col }} is NOT NUll) as count_not_nulls,
FROM
      `{{ var('src_project') }}.{{ var('src_schema') }}.{{ var('table_name') }}`
)
{%- if not loop.last %}
    UNION ALL
{%- endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am thinking if splitting the result_list as groups of 100, but I am not sure on how to generalize it.

Any idea on how to make this work for huge column datasets?

Comment: Unclear what the UNION operations are getting you other than query complexity, which is partly what the error is trying to communicate.   You don't appear to project the column name, so are you simply summing them after this?  Consider moving the for loop inside your select, and either generate an array type or just collapse all the counts into a SUM(), maybe?

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
#for each column in the table
SELECT
{% for col in results_list %}
      COUNTIF({{ col }} is NULL) as {{ col }}_count_nulls,
{% endfor %}
 FROM
      `{{ var('src_project') }}.{{ var('src_schema') }}.{{ var('table_name') }}`
 UNION ALL
SELECT
{% for col in results_list %}
     COUNTIF({{ col }} is NOT NUll) as {{ col }}_count_not_nulls
{% endfor %}
FROM
      `{{ var('src_project') }}.{{ var('src_schema') }}.{{ var('table_name') }}`
```

This will give you a table with ~700 columns and two rows, with your metrics.